# How do I unlock the Sun Cultist class?

Tags: moon-hunters

The 'secret' Sun Cultist class is locked at the start of the game. How do I make this class playable?

Answer (score 3):

While choosing a stage on the world map, some areas will be marked as having a "Sun Cultist Site".

When exploring these maps, you'll find an arena full of fire and smoke, in which a Sun Cultist will challenge you; after a boss fight, you'll receive a bunch of opals and such.

Upon completing the game, you'll unlock The Traitor constellation, which unlocks the Sun Cultist class.